# Understanding some linear algebra for KL derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, divergence-operator

Having some trouble understanding this proof in certain steps, even after trying to consult the matrix cookbook.

For two multivariate Gaussians $P_1, P_2 \in R^n$:

$KLD(P_1 || P_2) = E_{P_1}[\log P_1 - \log P_2]$

$= \frac{1}{2} E_{P_1}[-\log \det\Sigma_1 - (x - \mu _1)^T\Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x - \mu_1) + \log\det\Sigma_2 + (x - \mu _2)^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(x - \mu_2)]$

$= \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} + \frac{1}{2}E_{P_1}[- (x - \mu _1)^T\Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x - \mu_1)  + (x - \mu _2)^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(x - \mu_2)]$

$= \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} + \frac{1}{2}E_{P_1}[tr (\Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x - \mu_1)(x - \mu _1)^T)  + tr(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(x - \mu_2)(x - \mu _2)^T)]$

$= \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} + \frac{1}{2}E_{P_1}[tr (\Sigma_{1}^{-1}\Sigma_{1})  + tr(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(xx^T - 2x\mu^{T}_{2} + \mu_2\mu_{2}^T)]$

Why does $(x-\mu)(x-\mu) = \Sigma_1$?

$= \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2} tr(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(\Sigma_1 + \mu_1\mu_{1}^T - 2\mu_2\mu^{T}_{1} + \mu_2\mu_{2}^T)]$

What rule gets rid of the EV?

$= \frac{1}{2}(\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} - n + tr(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(\Sigma_1) + tr(\mu_{1}^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1 - 2\mu_{1}^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_{2}^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_2)$

$= \frac{1}{2}(\log \frac{\det\Sigma_2}{\det\Sigma_1} - n + tr(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(\Sigma_1) + (\mu_{2}-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(\mu_{2}-\mu_1))$

How do you reduce (what is the rule) that last term?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Why does $(x-\mu)(x-\mu) = \Sigma_1$?"

It doesn't, what you *do* have is
$$
E_{P_1}[(X_1-\mu_1)(X_1-\mu_1)^T] = \Sigma_1,
$$
and this is the definition of the covariance matrix $\Sigma_1$. This gives you the step
$$
\begin{align}
E_{P_1}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma_{1}^{-1}(X_1-\mu_1)(X_1-\mu_1)^T \right)\right] &= \operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma_{1}^{-1}E_{P_1}\left[(X_1-\mu_1)(X_1-\mu_1)^T \right]\right) = \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_{1}^{-1}\Sigma_1).
\end{align}
$$

> "What rule gets rid of the EV?"

The rule is simply taking the expected value, and using the fact that the expectation and trace operator are interchangeable, also recall that
$$
\Sigma_{1} = E_{P_1}[X_1 X_1^T] - \mu_1\mu_1^T,
$$ 
then
$$
\begin{align}
E_{P_1}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(X_1X_1^T-2X_1\mu_2^T+\mu_2\mu_2^T\right) \right] &= \operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}E_{P_1}\left[X_1X_1^T - 2X_1\mu_2^T + \mu_2\mu_2^T\right]\right) \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\left[\Sigma_1 + \mu_1\mu_1^T - 2\mu_1\mu_2^T + \mu_2\mu_2^T\right]\right)
\end{align}
$$
where I have repeatedly used the linearity of expectation.

> How do you reduce the last term?

The rule used at the end is the [trace trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761198/proof-on-trace-trick), which allows us to write for instance
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1\mu_2^T) &= \operatorname{Tr}(\mu_2^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1) \\
&= \mu_2^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1\\
&= \mu_1^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_2 \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\mu_1^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_2).
\end{align*}
$$
and combine this with the quadratic expansion
$$
(\mu_2-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}(\mu_2-\mu_1) = \mu_2^T\Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2 - 2\mu_2^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1 + \mu_1^T\Sigma_{2}^{-1}\mu_1.
$$

That should be all you need to follow the steps involved.